# How to have a html input correlate to a JavaScript variable?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am new to Google Apps Scripts and am trying to begin running a JavaScript function in HTML and have input values set to js variables. I would use the variable to set the time for a trigger. I do not know how to do so and can't find anything helpful. I was trying to have it all in HTML because it seems even more complicated to have the function in a javascript file.

```
 <script>
      function setrange() {
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('Start')
         .timeBased()
         .at(startdate)
         .create();
      }
    </script>
     <input type="datetime-local" id="startdate"/>
     <input type="button" value="Submit?" onclick="setrange()">
```

I wrote the script in js and then copied it into the HTML file. The Start function is on the js file.  The script does work with sample data on the js file. In theory, it should create the trigger on the date gathered from the input but I have yet to figure out how to do so in google apps script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing server and client code.  You can not run ScriptApp from the html client.  You need to use `google.script.run` to run the server code `getrange()`.  Here is an example.  Note that `startdate` is passed as a string and needs to be converted to a Date object.

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="datetime-local" id="startdate">
      <input type="button" value="Submit?" onclick="setrange()">
      <script>
        function setrange() {
          try {
            let startdate = document.getElementById("startdate").value;
            google.script.run.setrange(startdate);
          }
          catch(err) {
            alert(err);
          }
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function setrange(startdate) {
  try {
    let start = new Date(startdate);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('Start')
     .timeBased()
     .at(start)
     .create();
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)